# Django list display many to many field optimize SQL

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I have these following models. (example bought from http://www.jmccauli.com/posts/3-django-list_display-and-manytomany-fields/)

```
from django.db import models

class SomeOtherModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    others = models.ManyToManyField('SomeOtherModel')
```

Since Django wont support many to many field, to display it I must write a custom function

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('display_others',)
    def display_others(self):
        return ', '.join([ other.title for other in self.others.all() ])
```

But let say it I have 100 MyModel, each of them have 5 SomeOtherModel, then every time I display the list, the database will have to suffer at least 100 call for loading extra data. May I have another way to optimize this call? Can we do something like overwrite django queryset function to load all SomeOtherModel to memory

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyModel, self).queryset(request).select_related('others')
```

My question is, how can we optimize db call for this kind of model

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) could be what you are searching for.